# New line on mac in python

Tags: python, macos

```
task = raw_input("would you like to encrypt or decrypt", \\n\\r\\,":- ").lower()
```

does anyone know why this doesn't create a new line and just returns an error in python on mac.I can get this to work on windows, is it a different command on mac

Comment: Why don't you just use: `task = raw_input("would you like to encrypt or decrypt\n:- ").lower()`? I get a `SyntaxError` on Windows, so I don't know why you think it works.

Comment: this prints \n\\r\ aswell

Comment: I find that hard to believe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add your newlines directly in the string for your prompt, ie.

```
task = raw_input("would you like to encrypt or decrypt\r\n:- ").lower()
```

Answer (score 0):

I see few problems in what you wrote :

- the way you put it raw_input makes it look  like it  is taking 3 arguments ( separated by a comma ) while it takes 0 or one argument ([function official documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#raw_input) )

  - It shouldn't work on any os
  - the solution provided by jonrsharpe and Christian is what you are looking for